# Rails Admin: custom view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I've searched into this, but I've found nothing.

On the rails_admin views, on the left, there's the list of the models shown. I want to add a new entry to that list, lets call it 'Statistics'.
When I click on it, I want it to show on the main view a html file I've generated. And nothing else.

How do I do this?